# escape character \quote is added when using salesforce query in python

Tags: python, string

I am trying to query salesforce object from python .
the query string contains 'single quote so escape characters added automatically
and it failed because \backslash escape character added in the query

```
name=David's
 sql_query = (
            f"SELECT Id FROM contact WHERE Name = '{name}'"
        )

Expected string output:
sql_query = SELECT Id FROM contact WHERE Name = 'David's'

Actual string formed by script 
sql_query = SELECT Id FROM contact WHERE Name = 'David\'s'
```

Any help pls

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your `name` string variable in double quotes. Additionally, the way you are inserting `name` into the `sql_query` string is not correct.

Try this:

```
name = "David's"
sql_query = "SELECT Id FROM contact WHERE Name = " + name
```